# Проверка на принадлежность введённого номера мобильному телефону

Tags: java, android

Как с помощью `if else` проверить, что в `AutoCompleteTextView` введен номер мобильного телефона?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать класс [`PhoneNumberUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html). Если вы хотите проверить, что россиский номер телефона введен, вот пример:

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phoneNumber, "ru") != null
```

для этого нужна версия Android API level 21 или высше.

Answer (score 3):

Если кратко - то никак. Конечно можно что-то придумать для российских или конкретно каких-то других региональных номеров - но в общем случае никак (ну если вы не напишете парсер на пару сотен строчек)

Есть такая либа называется [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) - у нее есть Java инкарнация бинарники доступны на maven/gradle - там есть необходимые инструменты для опознания/парсинга номеров.

**Update**

Начиная с API (по-моему ICS) - libphonenumber входит в состав Android'а.

Comment: Входит, но API к ней нет, все равно приходится в приложениях внешнюю подключать